# How we patched Django to keep users logged in between sessions

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

We had a problem with a website which uses Django. Each time we upgrade Django, if a user is logged in with two or more different browsers, and then they login again from one browser - they are automatically logged out from all other sessions (browsers). Since we upgraded Django to new major versions about 5 times in the last year, this caused us a headache. We don't want to force users to have to login again and again between sessions. How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We checked and found out that this problem is caused due to a change in `PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations` between versions of Django. Each time we upgrade Django to a new major version (such as from 3.0 to 3.1), `PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations` changes. This causes the user's hashed password to be calculated again the next time the user logs in, which forces the user to remain logged out in all other sessions. I even created a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31970) with Django's tracking system.

There are two options to fix this issue. First, we can patch class `PBKDF2PasswordHasher` to keep the number of `iterations` constant, and also update `def must_update`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher


def patch():
    def must_update(self, encoded):
        # Update the stored password only if the iterations diff is at least 250,000.
        algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
        iterations_diff = abs(self.iterations - int(iterations))
        return ((int(iterations) != self.iterations) and (iterations_diff >= 250000))

    PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations = 180000  # Django 3.0.x
    PBKDF2PasswordHasher.must_update = must_update
```

And then in our base `AppConfig` class:

```py
class SpeedyCoreBaseConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'speedy.core.base'
    verbose_name = _("Speedy Core Base App")
    label = 'base'

    def ready(self):
        locale_patches.patch()  # Another patch
        session_patches.patch()  # This patch
```

Or, you can inherit a new class from `PBKDF2PasswordHasher`, change `iterations` and `def must_update`, and use your new class in the settings ([`PASSWORD_HASHERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-PASSWORD_HASHERS)). We used the first option, although it might be better to use the second option (inherit a new class) from a software engineering perspective. They both work.